# Django convert function-based views into class-based views

Tags: django

How would I go about converting these function-based views into class-based views?

```py
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.authentication import authenticate
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view

from .models import ApplicationUser
from .serializers import UserSerializer


@api_view(['POST'])
def register_user(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = UserSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)


@api_view(['POST'])
def user_login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.data.get('email')
        password = request.data.get('password')

        user = None
        if '@' in email:
            try:
                user = ApplicationUser.objects.get(email=email)
            except ObjectDoesNotExist:
                print('object does not exist exception')

        if not user:
            user = authenticate(email=email, password=password)

        if user:
            token, _ = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
            return Response({'token': token.key}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

        return Response({'error': 'Invalid credentials'}, status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)
```

I took these from: https://studygyaan.com/django/django-rest-framework-tutorial-register-login-logout